# Gradient background UL

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to set linear gradient background for `#month` but I've got a problem because this element has no height. The height is different for each month. I tried to get the height via jQuery but no luck. Example http://fiddle.jshell.net/2z4Fj/

Comment: In Chrome, I can't find any ul#month in your JSFiddle example. Is it possible that your usecase just doesn't have any ul#month?

Comment: there is ul with id month in div -> calendarPage -> calendarSlider

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
#calendarPage {
    background: linear-gradient(0deg,#bfbfbf,#fff);
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* this */
}
#month{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;  /* this */
    overflow: auto;  /* and this */
}
```

to your css. Here's a [**fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/2z4Fj/1/).

Comment: I think in #calendarPage overflow should be hidden to get rid of scroll bar.

Comment: @Dalli You're right. Missed that. When moving to previous month scroll-bar appears. Setting it to `hidden` fixes the problem. Updated the answer.